# How I can reset gauge metrics in spring boot after observed it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, prometheus, metrics

I have a spring boot microservice with gauge metrics.

```
     @Slf4j
     @Service
     public class HitControlService {
        private final AtomicInteger sentSuccessValue;
        private final AtomicInteger sentFailureValue;

        public HitControlService(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
           sentSuccessValue = meterRegistry.gauge("backend.success.hit", new AtomicInteger(0));
           sentFailureValue = meterRegistry.gauge("backend.failure.hit", new AtomicInteger(0));
        }
      }
```

My question is how I can reset those gauge metrics after Prometheus read the value from ***/actuator/prometheus*** (when observed).

Is there a way to intercept ***/actuator/prometheus*** or we have a specific configuration build in to achieve this.

Comment: As a principle, metrics should not change because their value has been read. So I don't think you should do that in the first place.

Answer (score -3):

use: any of following

```
AtomicInteger  sentSuccessValue = meterRegistry.gauge("backend.success.hit", new AtomicInteger(0));
sentSuccessValue.decrementAndGet();
sentSuccessValue.getAndSet();
sentSuccessValue.set(0);
```

Further read: https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_manually_incrementingdecrementing_a_gauge